# SQL Server : get average per week for the past 30 weeks

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to figure out how to get the average `CHECK_AMOUNT` per week for the past/last 30 weeks in SQL Server 2008.

I tried something like this (see below) but I I think that is for months and not for weeks.

```
SELECT TOP 30
    AVG(CHECK_AMOUNT) AS W2 
FROM 
    CHECKS 
WHERE 
    NOT UNT='256' 
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(DATE_GIVEN), MONTH(DATE_GIVEN)
```

Can anyone show me how I can make that possible please,

Thank you...

Comment: Why don't you find out how to obtain the week number? The web contains that information.

Comment: `WHERE NOT UNT = '256'` is equal to the more easily readable `WHERE UNIT <> '256'`

Comment: @usr I did try the web but none of the solutions where working for me, but the answer that fred gave helped me out alot. I just needed to know how to group by week really.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use a where clause comparing the dates:

```
  select AVG(CHECK_AMOUNT)
  from CHECKS
  WHERE NOT UNT='256' and DATEDIFF(d, Date_Given, getdate()) <= 30*7
```

I'm sorry; I misread the question.  You want the average per week.  Your original query is quite close

```
  select DATEDIFF(d, Date_Given, getdate())/7 as weeks_ago, AVG(CHECK_AMOUNT)
  from CHECKS
  WHERE NOT UNT='256' and DATEDIFF(d, Date_Given, getdate()) <= 30*7
  group by DATEDIFF(d, Date_Given, getdate())/7
```

I'm leaving the `where` clause in for selecting -- rather than using `top 30` -- in case there are weeks with no checks.

Comment: WOW, This is great! THANK YOU SO MUCH for this answer. The weeks without checks are really important also, Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

Can you try to add this to the group by clause ?

```
datepart(week, DATE_GIVEN)
```

Comment: This was a great help me for also, THANK YOU!

Answer (score 3):

Try to use Datepart

```
SELECT TOP 30  AVG(CHECK_AMOUNT) AS W2 FROM CHECKS WHERE NOT UNT='256' GROUP BY Datepart(week,DATE_GIVEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have run reports that cross over years and the Week has messed me up.
I use

YEAR(GETDATE()) * 100 + DATEPART(Week,GETDATE()) as my YearWeek value

Otherwise, if your data crosses over years, you'll be combining last year's week with this year's week.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).